# He is away until Wednesday. / He will be away until Wednesday

Tags: present-tense, future-constructions

In my grammar book I have the following:

> Jack **has gone away**. He **will be away** until Wednesday.

The first sentence is Present Perfect but the second one is Future Simple. Could you tell me why we don't use Present tense in that context?

> Jack **has gone away**. He **is away** until Wednesday.

Is it possible to use Present here, or because of "until Wednesday" must we use Future Simple? So, we can say "He is away." "He is away now." But can we say "He is away until Wednesday." if he has already gone away?

Comment: We can certainly say "Jack is away until Wednesday".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, both Present Simple and Future Simple can be used here. But there is a little difference depending on how you use them.
The simple present is used for scheduled arrangements like a timetable, so if you say "He is away until Wednesday", it is more like he has already planned to come back on Wednesday.
However, if you use "He will be away until Wednesday", it is more like a prediction, since the future simple tense is used with predictions.

The link [here](https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/simple_present_will_future_contrasted.htm) explains the difference between future simple and present simple in details.